# Getting path string from Excel in IronPython

Tags: excel, ironpython

I am trying to set working directory through IronPython. Its basically for ANSYS Workbench. I am getting the directory path from excel and i am storing it in a variable in IronPython.

```py
dirpath = worksheet.range["E25"].value
```

and I am giving this variable value as input path to `AbsUserPathName` and `chdir` commands.

```py
dir = AbsUserPathName(dirpath)
os.chdir(dirpath)
```

But none of it is working, it gives error as `expected str, got _comObject`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.aspx) you could use one of the following statements:

```py
dirpath = worksheet.Range["E25"].Text
```

or

```py
dirpath = worksheet.Cells[25, "E"].Text
```

or

```py
dirpath = worksheet.Cells[25, 5].Text
```

Your current statement exposes a COM object from the interop-API that might even represent multiple cells and therefore can not be used by chdir as there is no way of implicitly converting the range to a string.

Comment: You can either go the python way with `os.chdir` or set `Environment.CurrentDirectory` after having `from System import Environment` to use the corresponding .NET API. The result will be the same.